Using a N-channel MOSFET to connect and disconnect a load to GND
I want to connect a load to +60V by using of a n-channel MOSFET as follows:

The idea is that when the MOSFET is ON the load is connected to GND and it can draw current, and when the MOSFET is OFF, then the load can not draw current.

The signal that we apply to the MOSFET gate:


Why this is a bit distorted? I assume we should get a better pulse.

Second it seems there is 18A peak current of the load:


Is this Normal?

Drain voltage:


The input resistor of the signal generator is being considered as 10 Ohm, can it be related to this?
When I change it to 50 ohm, the peak current is smaller:

Would you please let me know if the system architecture is ok, or should change it a bit?

"know if the system architecture is ok" -- for what? The waveforms are simply what you've set up. What is the application? What is the actual load? How much power dissipation is acceptable, is efficiency any concern? etc.

Try changing the value of C1. You may need a soft start for this. If you load has interfaces to other ground referenced equipment, you probably want a high side switch.

@Tim Williams the actual load is already in the circuit (resistor and capacitor). The application of the circuit is to be able to connect and disconnect the load form GND at 3MHz, we do not care at this pint to efficiency.

@winny the C1 is our load and can not be changed, how can I consider the soft start in the circuit?

Change 56,7n to 56.7n. I suspect LTspice threats it as 56 F + error message in the log. Your 56 nF//24 ohm have a 13 ns time constant, so 3 MHz will just be some ripple on C1.

@winny The Vds waveform suggests it is read correctly.

Why does your load need a triangular waveform? There are better ways to construct it. As has been said before, there is no meaningful "connect and disconnect a load at 3MHz", you can completely forget your proposed operating principle. If the load is, like, a piezo stack, you don't have to obfuscate, we know what those are.

Sorry, 13 us, not 13 ns.

@TimWilliams Yes, the time constant is too short for 56 F. Perhaps LTspice XVII includes both . and ,? LTspice IV didn’t like decimal comma.

I believe there is no problem with gate-source voltage. The Ciss for the chosen MOSFET is 3 nF and 10 Ohm gate resistance, the rise times quite reasonable. The peaky current is due to sudden charging of the capacitor(56.7 nF).
